# how to work with sklearn pipeline, if features are already extracted?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

Hi I'm learning about text classification and if I have a dataset like this one:

[image]

My question: If I split training and testing set from the dataset, and do the feature extraction separately (I'm working with the word embedding).

Is it correct to pass the features from the training and testing dataset (names: feature_array_trainingset and feature_array_testingset) to the pipeline directly this way:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import svm

pipeline = Pipeline([('classifier',svm.SVC())])

pipeline.fit(feature_array_trainingset,train['Category'])

predictions = pipeline.predict(feature_array_testingset)
print (classification_report(predictions,test['Category']))
```

It returns the classification result, but I'm not quite sure whether I'm doing the correct process or not.

Comment: Depends on what you are doing in the "feature extraction" process. But the way you are fitting and predicting on your model looks correct.

Comment: @BICube thanks for the answer. For some reason, I had a problem with the process to extract feature (array) in the pipeline, so I decided to do it outside, both training and testing set with the same process and then put both of them to the classification.